# angularjs: how to use controllerAs to access the property of the isolated scope directive in template

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

I usually use the `controllerAs` syntax in my Angularjs project, which I think will be more clear in the template.
But in the current web app,I came into an issue as following:

```
function FirstCtrl() {
    this.name = 'First Controller';
}

function fooDirective() {
    return {
        scope: {
            testData:'='
         },
        name: 'ctrl',
        controller: 'FirstCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'foo',
        template: '<div>{{ foo.name }} {{testData}} {{foo.testData}}</div>',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {
             console.log($ctrl.name);
        }
    };
 }

angular
    .module('app', [])
    .directive('fooDirective', fooDirective)
    .controller('FirstCtrl', FirstCtrl);
```

the html part is as following:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <foo-directive test-data="'newdata'"></foo-directive>
</div>
```

and the live demo is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/baoqger/rbp1wyfa/

And my confusing point is in the template part:

```
template: '<div>{{ foo.name }} {{testData}} {{foo.testData}}</div>',
```

The `{{testData}}` can work well. But the `{{foo.testData}}` can't. How to fix the issue so I make access the property in the isolated scope object in controllerAs way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add `bindToController: true` to your directive definition:

```
function fooDirective() {
    return {
        scope: {
            testData:'='
         },
        name: 'ctrl',
        controller: 'FirstCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'foo',
        bindToController: true,
        template: '<div>{{ foo.name }} {{testData}} {{foo.testData}}</div>',
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {
             console.log($ctrl.name);
        }
    };
}
```

Applicable documentation is [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-) (note you have to scroll up a bit bc of their floating menu/header).

Comment: thank you. It works well.I missed such parameter...Thank you

Comment: You're welcome-- directive definitions can be kind of convoluted, it's easy to miss stuff in the documentation.  Glad to help!